# iis 7 subdomain rewrite reverse proxy to internal servers

Tags: url, iis, url-rewriting, reverse-proxy

On Server2008 systems, ARR/URL rewrite installed. Incoming traffic to ARR server ('pirate.mydomain.com'), that server in DMZ. Internal IIS servers (Server 2008/URL rewrite), single IIS site ('static.mydomain.com') containing dept sub-sites (static.mydomain.com/deptone, static.mydomain.com/depttwo, etc).

At server level on ARR server, ARR server proxy settings: 'enable proxy' enabled, 'useurl rewrite to inspect incoming requests' enabled, 'reverse proxy' set to 'pirate.mydomain.com'.

Intent is to have deptone.mydomain.com rewritten (not redirected) to static.mydomain.com/deptone .... and depttwo.mydomain.com rewritten to static.mydomain.com/depttwo .

URL should not change in the visitors' browser.

At IIS site level for 'pirate.mydomain.com', URL rewrite rule as follows:

```
<rule name="deptone redirect" stopProcessing="true">
<match url=".*" />
<conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
<add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(www.)?pirate.mydomain.com/(deptone)(.*)" />
</conditions>
<action type="Rewrite" url="http://static.mydomain.com/deptone{C:3}" appendQueryString="false" />
</rule>
```

THis is not working; I am getting 400.0 error ('max forwards limit').

Need guidance for URL rewrite rule for this process. Have been to the IIS forums/help, but still cannot get this working.

Thanks.